# SwiftUI + Combine framework + MVVM Publisher return empty list

Tags: mvvm, swiftui, observable, combine, swiftui-list

I am using the **MVVM architecture** in **Swift-UI** with **Combine Framework** and **Alamofire**.
However the data is being returned to observable object and is printing means the Alamofire and published data from api layers but from obserable object its not going to view.
I print the response and its printing in publisher but not returning back to view.

Following is the observable object.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class CountryViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var countryResponse:[CountryResponse] = []
    
    @Published var isLoggedIn = false
    @Published var isLoading = false
    
    @Published var shouldNavigate = false
    
    private var disposables: Set<AnyCancellable> = []
    
    var loginHandler = CountryHandler()
    
    @Published var woofUrl = ""
    
    private var isLoadingPublisher: AnyPublisher<Bool, Never> {
        loginHandler.$isLoading
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .map { $0 }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    
    private var isAuthenticatedPublisher: AnyPublisher<[CountryResponse], Never> {
        loginHandler.$countryResponse
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .map { response in
                guard let response = response else {
                    return []
                }
                print(response)
                return response
            }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    
    init() {
        countryResponse = []
        isLoadingPublisher
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .assign(to: \.isLoading, on: self)
            .store(in: &disposables)
        
        isAuthenticatedPublisher.map([CountryResponse].init)
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink(receiveCompletion: { [weak self] value in
              guard let self = self else { return }
              switch value {
              case .failure:
                self.countryResponse = []
              case .finished:
                break
              }
              }, receiveValue: { [weak self] weather in
                guard let self = self else { return }
                self.countryResponse = weather
            })
            .store(in: &disposables)
           //        isAuthenticatedPublisher
          //            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
         //            .assign(to: \.countryResponse, on: self)
        //            .store(in: &disposables)
    }
        
    public func getAllCountries(){
        loginHandler.getCountryList()
    }
    
    public func getAllUnis(_ id:Int){
        loginHandler.getCountryList()
    }
}
```

**View Code**

```
struct ContentViewCollection: View {
    
    @Binding var selectedCountryId:Int
    var axis : Axis.Set = .horizontal
    var viewModel:CountryViewModel
    @State var countries:[CountryResponse] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView (.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            HStack {
                ForEach(self.viewModel.countryResponse) { (postData) in
                    Button(action: {
                        self.selectedCountryId = postData.countryID ?? 0
                    }){
                        WebImage(url: self.imageURL(postData.countryName ?? ""))
                            .resizable()
                            .indicator(.activity)
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .frame(minWidth: 40,maxWidth: 40, minHeight: 40, maxHeight: 40, alignment: .center)
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        }.onAppear() {
            self.loadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show the View code? And where is the `print` statement where you say you receive the values?

Comment: @NewDev I updated the view code and add the print statement as well.

Comment: You need to make the property an ObservedObject: `@ObservedObject var viewModel: CountryViewModel`

Comment: Thank you so much perfecto!!!!

Comment: For last 2 days i was trying different solutions